# Angular dynamically assigning object does not bind

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to dynamically assign a object but the property value does not change.

when I try to 
$scope[key] = $scope.model[val];

where $scope.model[val] is an object which contains title property but {{title}} does not show

but if I set 
$scope[key] = {"title":"abc"}; It works

Can you please help me to make the 1st case work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

$scope.key = JSON.parse($scope.model[val]);